# Performance difference between assignment and conditional test

Tags: java

This question is specifically geared towards the Java language, but I would not mind feedback about this being a general concept if so.  I would like to know which operation might be faster, or if there is no difference between assigning a variable a value and performing tests for values.  For this issue we could have a large series of Boolean values that will have many requests for changes.  I would like to know if testing for the need to change a value would be considered a waste when weighed against the speed of simply changing the value during every request.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Boolean array[] = new Boolean[veryLargeValue];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        array[i] = randomTrueFalseAssignment;
    }
    for(int i = 400; i < array.length - 400; i++) { 
        testAndChange(array, i);
    }
    for(int i = 400; i < array.length - 400; i++) {
         justChange(array, i);
    }
}
```

This could be the testAndChange method

```
public static void testAndChange(Boolean[] pArray, int ind) {
    if(pArray) 
        pArray[ind] = false;
}
```

This could be the justChange method

```
public static void justChange(Boolean[] pArray, int ind) {
    pArray[ind] = false;
}
```

If we were to end up with the very rare case that every value within the range supplied to the methods were false, would there be a point where one method would eventually become slower than the other?  Is there a best practice for issues similar to this?

Edit: I wanted to add this to help clarify this question a bit more.  I realize that the data type can be factored into the answer as larger or more efficient datatypes can be utilized.  I am more focused on the task itself.  Is the task of a test "if(aConditionalTest)" is slower, faster, or indeterminable without additional informaiton (such as data type) than the task of an assignment "x=avalue".

Comment: How can you set `false` to a `pArray`?

Comment: Keep in mind that Java is a pass by value language, and there is no pointers as in C.

Comment: While a valid question, which I don't have the data to answer, just remember the quote "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Write code which is clear and maintainable over code which is unnoticeably faster.

Comment: Your code seems wrong: You cannot SET false to an array. And you cannot call a method that takes an argument with no arguments... Please provide the original source - otherwhise any attempt to help you is damned to fail.

Comment: If you care about performance, by not use a `boolean[]` which will be 1/4 the size or a `BitSet` which will be 1/32 the size?  This will make far more difference than testing the value.  BTW a missed branch can be 100x as expensive as an assignment.

Comment: @MaximePiraux Arrays (and all other objects, for that matter,) are passed by reference.

Comment: Sorry about those errors.  I have made the corrections.  let me know if you see any other errors.

Comment: I still can't tell what your `testAndChange()` is supposed to be doing.  `if(!pArray[ind]) pArray[ind] = false;`?  There's a distinct possibility that the optimizer might just remove that whole statement, including the function call.

Comment: Also a BitSet allows you to clear 64-bit blocks at a time i.e. it uses an array of longs.  This can be up to 64x faster than setting one value at a time.

Comment: @5w3rv0: The test should also be modified to `if(pArray[ind])`...

Comment: @TrippKinetics I am sorry but I do not think i understand your issue.  I test (pArray[ind]) not (!pArray[ind]) this would cause all trues to be changed to false.

Comment: @5w3rv0 Ah, ok.  Doesn't change my observation, however.  There's a distinct possibility that the optimizer might just take care of the whole thing for you.  So, in other words, unless you actually write it and profile the bytecode, I'm not certain you can know the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments so far.  I think that I might have been unclear by providing an example however.  I am more concerned with the speed of the two tasks that I mentioned.  Is the speed of a test "if(aCondition)" is in any way discernibly different from the speed of an assignment "x=value"

Comment: @TrippKinetics I was worried that might be a possibility.  I thought it would be good to attempt to find out though.  Maybe there are other possibilities but you are probably right.

Comment: @5w3rv0 Assuming all other things being equal, an assignment will be faster than a conditional followed by an assignment.  It's one extra instruction.  But you can almost never assume that things are equal.  Is the architecture storing the output of the assignment in register or memory?  Is the performance of the branch unit better or worse than the load/store unit?

Comment: I'm not the convinced that the two are strictly equal. The difference is assign or not assign - which has implications for concurrency. I don't know what atomicity guarantees Java has for concurrent operations on a boolean.

Comment: @Mysticial Good point, that.  I hadn't even thought of concurrency.  My observations really start to take effect in really tiny architectures, so I didn't even think of stuff like that.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I believe that I may have become to concerned with the details of something that can more or less be disregarded.  It seems that the speed of these two actions would more likely be gauged on the data that is manipulated or hardware involved rather than the actions themselves.  I think I should start looking at them as simply an operation to be included in the calculation of O(n) with performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TrippKinetics points out, there is a semantical difference between the two methods. Because you use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, it is possible that one of the values is a `null` reference. In that case the first method (with the `if`-statement) will throw an exception while the second, simply assigns values to all the elements in the array.

Assuming you use `boolean[]` instead of `Boolean[]`. Optimization is an undecidable problem. There are very rare cases where adding an `if`-statement could result in better performance. For instance most processors use cache and the `if`-statement can result in the fact that the executed code is stored exactly on two cache-pages where without an `if` on more resulting in cache faults. Perhaps you think you will save an assignment instruction but at the cost of a fetch instruction and a conditional instruction (which breaks the CPU pipeline). Assigning has more or less the same cost as fetching a value.

In general however, one can assume that adding an `if` statement is useless and will nearly always result in slower code. So you can quite safely state that the `if` statement will slow down your code *always*.

More specifically on your question, there are faster ways to set a range to false. For instance using bitvectors like:

```
long[] data = new long[(veryLargeValue+0x3f)>>0x06];//a long has 64 bits

//assign random values

int low = 400>>0x06;
int high = (veryLargeValue-400)>>0x06;
data[low] &= 0xffffffffffffffff<<(0x3f-(400&0x3f));
for(int i = low+0x01; i < high; i++) {
    data[i] = 0x00;
}
data[high] &= 0xffffffffffffffff>>(veryLargeValue-400)&0x3f));
```

The advantage is that a processor can perform operations on 32- or 64-bits at once. Since a boolean is one bit, by storing bits into a `long` or `int`, operations are done in parallel.

Comment: This is what `BitSet.clear(400, veryLargeValue-400)` does for you. ;)

Comment: But `Boolean`s are objects, and isn't the size of a `boolean` undefined?  Please note the case.

Comment: @TrippKinetics: well a `Boolean` is indeed an object thus there is a third state: `null`. This will result in 32 bits per `Boolean` (for the reference, and some for the object itself). I think the question is more specific to `boolean[]`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: True that, but the problem with some of these datastructures is that they don't give insight in why they work faster. Some of my fellow students for instance have no clue in how a `HashMap` works. This is crucial to understand why some code (doesn't) scales.

Comment: @CommuSoft The original poster had it defined specifically as `Boolean[]` in their code...

Comment: @TrippKinetics: True, but the code never ever checks for `null` pointer values. Anyhow, one can convert the code so it supports three-state-logic (using two bits per value, one indicating that the value is (not) `null` a second that specifies the effective value).

Comment: @CommuSoft If you understand `CS 101 - How a hash table works`, you know most of what you need to know about HashMap.  I know Java tries to insulate developers from the details but I also think you should expect professional developers to know the basics.

Comment: @TrippKinetics The code assumes that the `Boolean` cannot be `null`  If you really need a `Boolean` instead of a `boolean` you could use two bits per Boolean, or use a more compact encoding.

Comment: @PeterLawrey A few of the developers I've worked with know how to *use* hash maps, but don't really know how to tune the hash function for space, which can also be a problem at times.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You could definitely hand tune the encoding, but I'm still not convinced that the original poster had anything in mind other than the stock JVM.

Comment: @TrippKinetics: I've updated my answer. Kudos for specifying that the two methods are sematically different. :)

Comment: @CommuSoft I am often surprised developers don't understand how integer division works even though my 9 year recent didn't this in primary school. e.g. why is `10/20 == 0` You forget these things if you don't use them.  Is it because integer division is too hard or should we remember more from primary school. I am not sure either way.

Comment: @TrippKinetics we can only go on the code shown and there is no need for `Boolean` here only, `boolean`  Using wrapper types when there is no need for a `null` value is a common mistake in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the information @CommuSoft.  This answer makes me see that my answer may likely be more system based than I thought.  I will hold off for now on selecting an answer to see what else comes up though.

Comment: @5w3rv0 in short, you are worrying about the wrong things if your purpose is to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you @CommuSoft.  After re-reading your answer I understand it better.  I must have missed it the first time.  It appears that I am trying to compare something that I should be considering the same for performance calculations.  I should be more concerned with other areas for performance improvements.

Comment: @5w3rv0: Well in the academic world, one focuses more on *time complexity*. This is the behavior on how an application scales when the size of the problem is increased. And using some predefined data structures will also yield some improvement. Of course the tweaks you propose will have some impact, but in most cases they will not be significant compared to the rest of the program.